# I always get this error in Haskell when I try to do :load Rpn.hs

Tags: haskell

This is the code I have for trying to implement a reverse Polish notation evaluator:

```
step :: [Int] -> String -> [Int] 
step (x:y:ys) "*" = (x * y):ys 
step (x:y:ys) "+" = (x + y):ys 
step (x:y:ys) "-" = (y - x):ys 
step xs numberString = read numberString:xs

rpn :: [String] -> Int
rpn = head . foldl step[] . words
```

and this is error I keep getting when I do :load Rpn.hs :

```
Rpn.hs:9:7: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘[Char]’ with ‘Char’
      Expected type: [String] -> Int
        Actual type: String -> Int
    • In the expression: head . foldl step [] . words
      In an equation for ‘rpn’: rpn = head . foldl step [] . words
  |
9 | rpn = head . foldl step[] . words
  |       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

I think the problem is with the foldl function but I am not quite sure about how to resolve it. Please, kindly guide me on what to do.

Comment: What's the definition of the `step` function?

Comment: It makes perfect sense that you always get exactly the same error. But with the current state of the question, we can not help much. Please post the *relevant parts* of your code file (that means that `step` function, and all other functions that depend on `step` directly or indirectly).

Comment: Why? `step` has nothing to do with this error. It could be `undefined` and you'd still have the same type error.

Comment: @Joseph It's always good to provide code that reproduces the exact error asked about, to make it easier to diagnose. Without the definition of `step`, it's clear that you get a *different* error: step is not in scope. Potential answerers may not be inclined to spend time realizing that `step = undefined` reproduces the issue.

Comment: @mia that's just the type of `step`, he's asking for the definition (i.e., what instructions it actually performs)

Comment: Sorry I am kind of new to this prolog thing and keep getting confused I hope this is what this what you mean by the definition.                                                                step (x:y:ys) "*" = (x * y):ys
step (x:y:ys) "+" = (x + y):ys
step (x:y:ys) "-" = (y - x):ys
step xs numberString = read numberString:xs

Comment: @mia I'm pretty sure that's haskell and not prolog, but no worries!

Comment: yes I meant Haskell I am also in the process of learning prolog that's why I mixed it up haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have a function like `f = foo . bar . baz`, it can be written in a pointful way as `f x = foo (bar (baz x))`. In your case, you'd have `rpn x = head (foldl step [] (words x))`. The problem is now apparent: you're calling `words x`, and `words` has type `String -> [String]`, so `x` should have type `String`. However, `rpn :: [String] -> Int`, and `x` is the first argument to `rpn`, so `x` should have type `[String]`. Since `x` can only have one type, it can't be both `String` and `[String]`, so the compiler is making you fix this discrepancy. There are two different ways to fix this, depending on what you want `rpn` to do:

1. Change the type of `rpn` to `String -> Int`, and leave its definition alone
2. Remove `. words` from the definition of `rpn`, and leave its type alone